# Early 70's TV show - heros and bad guys shoot needles from their fingers

Tags: story-identification, tv

This is going back 50 years (1971), and was prolly a rerun at the time

I have a memory of a TV show that my babysitter and her brothers and sisters and I watched that was black & white (so was our TV, but I'm pretty sure the show was) and had a very Twilight Zone low budget, filmed in a minimal studio set feel to it

The good guys and bad guys were both "secret organizations" (common theme back then), and they fought each other with needles they could shoot from their fingers. I seem to recall the "bad guys" were also sometime monsters or "horrific creatures"

I don't know if this was a series of its own or just an episode from something else.

Comment: This sounds like an early Americanized Japanese production, like Johnny Sokko’s dueling spy groups Gargoyle vs. Unicorn, but I think they had machine guns not needler guns.

Comment: Live action or animation? English?

Comment: live action. yes, I now live in Japan & had the thought while writing this that it sounded very Japanese, especially the weird "monsters" that I very vaguely remember